# Node cluster not listening, cluster exits and not respond

Tags: node.js, windows, node-cluster

This problem i got on my machine only. I tried my code on other machines it works perfectly, I didn't got any solution because there is no code level problem, may be its OS problem or may be Nodejs version problem, I don't know.

> **Operating Syatem**: Window 7 Professional 64-bit
>
> **Nodejs version**: 4.4.3

Code

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Fork workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }


    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log("worker %s died", code);
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    var express = require('express');
    var http = require('http');

    // init app
    var app = express();

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.send('home page');
    });

    function createServer(app) {
        return http.createServer(app);
    }

    app.locals.server = createServer(app);

    app.locals.server.listen(8080, function() {
        console.info("server online");
    });
}
```

logs on command line

```
server online
server online
server online
server online
```

When i hit http://localhost:8080, then new logs are

```
worker 3221225477 died
server online
```

and no data got on browser, continuously loading on browser.

Please help.

Comment: is port `8080` open on your machine ? Some firewall might blocking connection over that port.

Comment: @ErrHunter I'm running it locally and it works fine without cluster,

Comment: Have you tries using [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). Install and try using it's `Cluster mode`, if it works with that then we might have problem with our implementation, if it doesn't work over there too means its some other problem, mostly OS or network or something.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't define any route, where your server can get the request.

As per your code you can define one route in your `else` condition

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.send('home page');
    })
```

And hit the URL`http://localhost:8080`.

Hope it works

Comment: Agreed, it's probably a 404 getting swallowed and killing the worker.

Comment: Yes, server still trying to response but can't, so probably it'll be killed

Comment: No, I mean the worker that took the request died (see his console output to that effect), I was saying it's likely because his app isn't handling the exception.  The "server online" statement after it indicates that the cluster restarted the worker afterward.

Comment: @abdulbarik after adding it same problem

Comment: @Gaurav Can you update your question with updated code? since I checked same in my pc and it's working

Comment: Yes, i already told you its working code, but its not working on my machine.

Comment: My node version is `v6.9.2`